# Which compiler, compiled this file?

Tags: c, gcc, gnu, gnu-make, armcc

I am using gnu gcc and armcc to compile a few C files. How can I get the information about which compiler compiled which file?

Ex: test.cpp is being compiled by armcc or gnu gcc.

The makefile is very complicated and I am looking out for a command by which I can check which compiler compiled which file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have access to the indeterminate object files ?

Comment: Perhaps the object file format might give you some clues

Comment: Yes, I have access to the .o files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you can look at the file with a hex editor and tell if the compiler wrote its name into the file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there's an easier way, but you can find it embedded in the binary with gcc (at least on my platform):

```
$ hexdump -C foo | grep -A2 GCC

00001030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  47 43 43 3a 20 28 55 62  |........GCC: (Ub|
00001040  75 6e 74 75 2f 4c 69 6e  61 72 6f 20 34 2e 37 2e  |untu/Linaro 4.7.|
00001050  32 2d 32 32 75 62 75 6e  74 75 33 29 20 34 2e 37  |2-22ubuntu3) 4.7|
```

Comment: This does not work with executable files (or .o files) compiled with gcc here (gcc on OS X).  This seems to be platform-dependent.

Comment: @RandyHoward- though actually that may be because it's clang behind the scenes?

Comment: gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)      <<>> Regardless, his question was about multiple compilers.  I'm not sure this method is a valid answer.

Comment: Yup - the llvm bit. I think it's just a gcc frontend to llvm, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0):

Some compiler embedd compiler name and version in to the binrary, but not all. We can also embedd whatever information we want into the binary.

```
gcc -DCOMPILER_DETAILS='"gcc 4.3.3"' temp.c
```

In `temp.c` use the macro `COMPILER_DETAILS` in any place, like just use it in `printf`. So that this string literal will be embedd in the generated binary file. Dont assign this string to unused variable, compiler will not embedd because of optimization.